# Alternate to using backspace in vim

Tags: vim

When I do a mistake in vim, I use backspace, because changing to command mode and use 'x' is longer, but maybe is other way to do it vim-way?

Comment: You could repeat the mistake everywhere and afterwards do a find and replace on all :). Seriously, I doubt you'll find a better way than using the plain old backspace.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ctrl-w` to erase the last word, `ctrl-u` to erase the entire line you're on.

Answer (score 9):

In insert mode `ctrl+h` does the same thing as the backspace key (i.e. deletes one character backwards).

Comment: Some terminals actually send `<C-h>` when you type backspace: this is the control code that means «move cursor one character back», but most terminal programs including vim remap it to «delete previous character». For example, zsh will delete character from its command buffer and send «<C-h><Space><C-h>» to terminal when you press «<C-h>» (space is here to blank already typed character).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `u` to undo. However it tends to erase the whole last line you typed...

Depending on the situation you can use the following text objects :

- `ciw` to erase and rewrite the current word
- `c$`  to erase and rewrite everything to the end of the line
- `c^`  to erase and rewrite everything to the beginning of the line
- `ci)` to change the content of parentheses

See `:help text-objects` for more.

If you need to change a single letter, the Vim way could be to use `r` to replace the wrong letter.

1. type `tje home`
2. Put your cursor on `j` using `fj` or `Fj` depending if your cursor is after or before `j`
3. Type `r` and then `h`

Comment: I think OP's intention is to stay in insert-mode.

Comment: @Lieven : Good point, in this case I don't think you can type less than a key to correct the issue.

Comment: +1 for reminding me of the `fjr` sequence. As a vim noob, it's much more convenient than what I did to date.